# message AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool not a function in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use the AWS Cognito User Pool in my AWS Lambda Function.  I saw in the tutorial that you would need to include the amazon-cognito-identity.min.js in your code but I am not sure how to do this in node js.  I use npm install for the external modules but i don't think aws-cognito-identity exists yet as a module.

I installed aws-sdk but the function AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool does not exist in the SDK.

by the way, here's my code in Lambda:

```
'use strict';
 var AWS= require('aws-sdk');


AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' // your identity pool id here
});

// Need to provide placeholder keys unless unauthorised user access is enabled for user pool
//AWSCognito.config.update({accessKeyId: 'anything', secretAccessKey: 'anything'})

var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx',
    ClientId : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
};
var userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

module.exports.handler = function(event, context, cb) {

var attributeList = [];
var email = event.email;
var username=event.username;
var password = event.password;

var dataEmail = {
    Name : 'email',
    Value : email
};
var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name : 'phone_number',
    Value : '+15555555555'
};
var attributeEmail = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
var attributePhoneNumber = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    username = result.user;
 }
);  return cb(null, username);
};
```

and here is the error message I'm getting when testing the Lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool is not a function",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try this command "npm install -g" and then check

Comment: that didn't work as well.  The problem is that the function itself is not found inside the aws-sdk source code for javascript.  I can see it in the amazon-cognito-identity.min.js file.  I'm thinking that I can just copy that bit into my code but it does not feel like it is the right solution.

Comment: just found that the server side implementation is not yet available until GA:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233825&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, I just found this incredible repo:

https://github.com/kndt84/amazon-cognito-identity-js
and the associated npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js-node

It works. Good solution for now (July 2017) while waiting for the General Availability release of Cognito where this will be fixed in AWS (some people  have been facing the issue since October 2016).

```
npm install amazon-cognito-identity-js-node
```

and

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var CognitoSDK = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js-node');
AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails = CognitoSDK.AuthenticationDetails;
AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool = CognitoSDK.CognitoUserPool;
AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser = CognitoSDK.CognitoUser;
```

You can also do the same for other items like `CognitoUserAttribute`.

Note that you will have to change

```
const attributeEmail = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
```

to:

```
const attributeEmail = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail.Name, dataEmail.Value);
```